# iOS How works refresh screen in general on system level

Tags: ios, user-interface

I need some information about that how works refresh screen in general on system level.

Which system method is called every time for drawing screen content?

Android has choreographer for refresh screen. What is analog for iOS?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. This? https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Comment: @Arthur great thanks, I was looking for actually this. If you will add this as answer I will accept this.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS this works a bit different.

If you'd want to override screen drawing for a specific view, you would subclass the view and override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method.
You then use `super drawRect:` to draw the original contents, and add your own content using `CGContext` for example.

Comment: No, I need system method which called every (for example every 1 millisecond) time

Comment: Oh right, don't think it's possible. You'd have to create one yourself `NSTimer` or use a 2D / 3D library. (SpriteKit / Metal). iOS just calls those functions whenever it thinks they're needed!

Comment: I understand that iOS not works like Android, but think exist analog of choreographer for iOS or other thing which call refresh screen

Comment: I not try call or override this method. I need information about method